# Arranging DIVs on webpage

Tags: html, css, css-float, grid-layout

I am trying to display div's on screen in form of grid. All divs  have same width but different size. e.g. size of small div is `width=100px` and `height=100px`  and there are few divs of `width=100px` and `height=200px`.
   I want to arrange them so that it will take all the space on screen.  There should not be any empty space.

Below is some html code.

```
    <style> 
div {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    -webkit-animation:myfirst 5s;
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation:myfirst 5s;
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
}
.div1 {
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
    -webkit-animation:myfirst 5s;
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation:myfirst 5s;
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="div1"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Its please see below for its output.

[image]

Please help...

Comment: Have you looked at http://gridster.net/?

Comment: thanks @stubailo I don't want to use any framework.  I just want to know css styling code. Because I cant use this framework in my project.

Comment: do you want only five column or it can vary????

Comment: It can vary.  Width of images is configurable.  But it will remain same for all the images in grid.

Comment: If it can vary then you'll need to either build or use a plugin

Comment: I dont think there is any way to achieve this with only CSS.

Comment: I had a similar issue awhile back... I basically created floated columns then wrote JavaScript to always add the next element to the shortest column. If this solution sounds like it might work for you, I can dig up that code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things I would like to know: Are the squares randomly generated? is there a "tall" square in each line? can you use jquery or javascript to dynamically create the grid and set the positions? If the grid is predetermined, then go through each "short" div that is not set properly and give it a

```
margin-top:-100px
```

but don't forget to account for the margins you have so the grid looks clean

**UPDATE BASED ON COMMENT FROM ORIGINAL POSTER**

Since the numbers are coming from the database, you can systematically fill the page based on the max height of 120px. So for example: (pseudo-code)

```
create div:height 120px
for(each number from database)
{
    for(each created div)
    {
        if( it fits in the div )
        { 
            add number to div
        }
    }
    if( it did not fit in any div )
    {
        create new div:height 120px
        add number to new div
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  there are 4 different hights for squres. 30px, 60px, 90px, 120px.  I want to generate these divs from the information that exists in database.  Order of divs can be anything.  Just want to make sure that UI is properly occupy.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use two div wrapper columns and put the right div in a div of its own. Then you can create appropriate horizontal spacing for all the divs except the right column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property `position: absolute` to give proper positions to your divisions.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/q7UxY/4/

I use javascript to arrange the divs by finding the smallest height for each column and place it.

```
$('.box').each(function(element) {
    var index = findColumnIndex(columns);
    $box = $(this);
    $box.css({
        'position' : 'absolute',
        'left': ($box.width() * index + spacing * (index + 1) ) + 'px',
        'top': (columns[index] + spacing) + 'px'
    });
    console.log('left : "'+($box.width * index + spacing * (index + 1) ) + 'px'+'", top : "'+(columns[index] + spacing) + 'px'+'"');
    columns[index] += spacing + $box.height();
});
```